Cannot access shared folder via local network
Right after turned on Advanced Network Settings > Advanced Sharing Settings > All networks > Public Folder Sharing and shared the folder, the folder still does not appear in Network. It does via \\localhost or \\IP_ADDRESS. I can't also accessing it from other device through local network.
I also noticed that on some demos it shows that we can switch to older Windows 10 version view so there will be an option for Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in the Public folders, so by turning it on, it will shows up in Network and can be accessed from other device.
